# How to display Firestore datetime

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I use React + Firestore(Firebase). And the application logs datetime `created at` every time the post is created. And I use `firebbase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`.

Create code:

```
export function updateProfile(uid, values) {
  return dispatch => {
    databaseRef
      .doc(uid)
      .update({
        name: values.name,
        created_at: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
      })
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({ type: CREATE_ITEM });
      });
  };
}
```

Fetch code:

```
// Fetch profile
export function fetchItem(id) {
  return dispatch => {
      databaseRef
        .doc(id)
        .get()
        .then(doc => {
          dispatch({ type: FETCH_ITEM, payload: doc.data() });
        });
  };
}
```

But datetime objects in Firestore are rendered. So it's not simple to display in the view.
I try to like `{item.created_at}`. But the error occurs.

The error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {seconds, nanoseconds}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

My final goal is to display how long time ago the post is created like `2 hours ago`, `1 days ago`. But my first step is to display this.

### Additional

I tried `toDate()`.

```
<p>{item.created_at.toDate()}</p>

=> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toDate' of undefined
```

I tried `Timestamp.toDate()`.

```
<p>{item.created_at.Timestamp.toDate()}</p>

=> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Timestamp' of undefined
```

Comment: Hi, you should use the `toDate` method to convert a Timestamp to a JavaScript Date object, as detailed in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp.html#todate).

Comment: I did try but `Cannot read property 'toDate' of undefined` error occurs.

Comment: Note that `toDate()` is a method, so you should call it as `timestamp.toDate()`. But the error you are receiving shows that your value of timestamp is undefined. You may check if you get a correct value.

Comment: `Timestampseconds: 1580727807nanoseconds: 999000000` I can get correct timestamp...

Comment: Pls share your entire code, in order for us to understand how you get the is value.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have added in details.